# Battery consumption while TCP is open for ADB via wifi can connect

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, adb, battery

My question is related to ADB over Wifi. I've found an article:
http://stuffandtech.blogspot.de/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html
and that works for me, but I would like to know if keeping TCP open all the time actually will cause any significant battery drain. Of course I am talking about opened, but not used.

After some time connection seems to die by timeout: device, that used to be connected remotely

```
#adb devices
List of devices attached 
192.168.2.2:5555    device
```

disappears from adb devices:

```
#adb devices
List of devices attached
```

, so new

```
#adb connect <ip>:<port>
```

is needed. On the other hand, if I scan with nmap, I still see this TCP open (naturally, how else new adb connect would work!):

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.2
Host is up (0.017s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5555/tcp open  freeciv
```

So, again, the question is: does keeping this TCP open forever will consume battery if adb is not actually connected?

Thanks

Comment: From my experience, battery is draining very fast when ADB over WIFI is turned on.