# How secure is adb tcpip (ADB Over Wi-Fi)

Tags: android, debugging, networking, tcp, adb

I would like to understand how secure is `adb tcpip` (ADB Over Wi-Fi) ?

Since I can change adb to always be available over Wi-Fi , does it make my device vulnerable ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35989150/1778421

Comment: What about battery consumption, in case I keep adb over wifi on?

Comment: The question regarding battery consumption was raised here too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036820/battery-consumption-while-tcp-is-open-for-adb-via-wifi-can-connect

Answer (score 3):

To recive ADB connection from other PC you should ALLOW every MAC to use network ADB connection to your device. Since you have allowed only your PC to connect to your phone over ADB - you are vulnerable only if someone cracks your "Whitelisted" device (your lap or PC). From witch attackers can teoreticaly connect to Android.

Comment: But if the connection is active and passes an insecure network the authenticated network connection could be attacked and e.g. commands could be injected into the connection.